# JavaScript sometimes prevents server event from firing with asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have what I thought was a pretty straightforward javascript issue, but I'm starting to go nuts trying to figure out my problem.

I have a slow page, and it was possible for users to click submit, then click another button while waiting on the page to load, it was creating issues.  I thought I could display a please wait message and disable the submit button on click.  Below is the function, I am using asp.net 3.5 so there's a name mangling issue, because of this I was using a getElemenetsByName and scanning for the right items (not awesome but it seems to work).  When I run this, the button becomes disabled, but then the page just sits there, the server never gets called.  I tried in firefox and I didn't see any errors in firebug, but when I set a breakpointon the server, the server def does not get called.  I tried returning true in case there was an output expected, but nada.  When I commend out the content of `processing(){ // stuff }` then it works fine, so something in there seems to be killing me.

```
function processing() {
    var pleaseWaitID = "lblPleaseWait";
    var submitBtnName = "btnSubmit";
    var submitControl = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    var pleaseWaitlbls = document.getElementsByName(pleaseWaitID);

    for (pleaseWait in pleaseWaitlbls) {
       if (pleaseWaitlbls[pleaseWait].style != null) {
            pleaseWaitlbls[pleaseWait].style.visibility="visible";
       }
    }

    for (submitButton in submitControl) {
       if (submitControl[submitButton].name != null) {
           if (submitControl[submitButton].name.search(submitBtnName) != -1) {
               submitControl[submitButton].disabled = "disabled";
           }
       }
    }

    return true;
}
```

.....

```
 asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" SkinID="MainAction" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick = "javascript:processing();"
 OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" meta:resourcekey="btnSubmitResource1"
```

Any ideas on what I've screwed up here?

Thanks you for your time.

Comment: Please verify that the tag names are correct by viewing the source of the rendered HTML.

Comment: The rendered html gives a very very long name tag due to the asp.net name mangling (I think this is resolved in later versions of asp.net) so it's something like contentBasepage_c1_popupmodal_btnSubmit for both the name and ID tags.  EDIT: ALSO I think it's correct because it appears to find the button, disable it, and display the wait text, but then the server isn't called.  It just sits.

Comment: Rendered HTMLis:  input type="submit" name="ctl00$mainContentHolderMVPTO$btnSubmit" class="button main" id="ctl00_mainContentHolderMVPTO_btnSubmit" onclick="javascript:processing();" value="Submit"

Answer (score 0):

[Asp.net Custom user control button. How to stop multiple clicks by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592229/asp-net-custom-user-control-button-how-to-stop-multiple-clicks-by-user)

I had the same type of problem this may or may not help.